# Compute principal divisor for a rational function on a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

During the lecture we defined the principal divisor of a rational function on a smooth curve as it follows:

Consider the smooth curve $C\subseteq\mathbb{P}^2$. Take $g\in{K(C)^*}$. Then the principal divisor is $(g)=\sum{\nu_P(g)P}\in Div^0_{C}$. Where $\nu_P(g)\in\mathbb{Z}$ is the order of the zero, if $P$ is a zero, or minus the order of the pole, if $P$ is a pole.

I have some troubles computing it, in particular computing $\nu_P(g)$. 
A particular case can be:
I have the smooth curve $C:y^2=x^3+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{13}$ and I have to compute the principal divisor of the rational function $g=\frac{x^2}{y}$.

What I tried:

1. I homogenized both the curve and the function. So I get:
   $g=\frac{x^2}{yz}$ and $C:y^2z=x^3+z^3$
2. I want to find the zeros, so I have to find the points that satisfy:
   $x^2=0$ and $y^2z=x^3+z^3$.

   So I found $(0:1:0)$ and $(0:1:1)$ and $(0:-1:1)$.
   How do I find the order of these zeros?
3. I want to find the poles, so I have to find the points that satisfy:
   $yz=0$ and $y^2z=x^3+z^3$. I have found $(0:1:0)$, $(-1:0:1)$, $(4:0:1)$,   $(-3:0:1)$. How can I find the orders?

What I know is that the sum of the orders of the points has to be (if i'm not         wrong) $6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divisor of the rational function    $g=\frac{x^2}{yz}$ on  the curve $C$ given by $ y^2z=x^3+z^3$ is $$2\cdot(0:1:1)  +2\cdot(0:-1:1)-(-1:0:1)-(4:0:1)-(-3:0:1)-(0:1:0)                $$

**Justification: an example of calculation**
On the affine part $z=1$ of $C$, the curve has equation $f=y^2-x^3+1=0$ and the rational function is $g=\frac{x^2}{y}$.
The point $A=(0:1:1)$ has affine cordinates $(0,1)$ and at that point $x$ is a uniformizing parameter (because $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}(A)\neq0$ ).
Thus the order at $A$ of $g=\frac{x^2}{y}$ is $2$ (notice that $y$ neither vanishes nor has a pole at $A$ so that its order is $0$  at $A$)

Comment: Thank you for the answer ;) but it's not clear to me how can I find this 2 before (0:1:1) (and also before (0:-1:1))

Comment: Dear Atlas, I have added a justification which might help you.

Comment: Thank you Georges Elencwajg, this helps me a lot!

Comment: Is the line about "$f=y^2-x^3+1$" meant to read $f = y^2 - x^3 - 1$? And if so, does this change anything else about the answer?

Comment: I know this is a really old Q&A, but I had a question about your answer - you have the zeros & the pole co-ordinates which seems to work if I plug it into the equation. However, what is the formal procedure for finding these poles & zeros & their multiplicities?

Comment: Also while writing out the divisor shouldn't multiplicity of a zero/pole be used instead of the order of the zero/pole point? Why does the original question refer to the order of the point instead of the multiplicity?